# python socket.connect -> timed out why?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm fairly naive in this regard. I'm not sure why my connection is timing out. Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket

def socket_to_me():
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
    ans = s.recv(1024)
    print(ans)
```

the trace back generated by this code

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "logger.py", line 12, in <module>
    socket_to_me()
  File "/home/drew/drewPlay/python/violent/networking.py", line 7, in socket_to_me
    s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
timeout: timed out
```

Comment: From port 21 I assume it's an FTP port you're trying to open. Have you tried to connect using an FTP client to make sure the network / FTP server is OK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to alter the default timeouts for all new sockets, instead you can just set the timeout of that particular connection. The value is a bit low though, so increasing it to 10-15 seconds will hopefully do the trick.

First, do this:

```
s = socket.socket()
```

Then:

```
s.settimeout(10)
```

And you should use "try:" on the connect, and add:

```
except socket.error as socketerror:
    print("Error: ", socketerror)
```

This will bring up the systems error message in your output and handle the exception.

Modified version of your code:

```
def socket_to_me():
    try:
        s = socket.socket()
        s.settimeout(2)
        s.connect(("192.168.95.148",21))
        ans = s.recv(1024)
        print(ans)
        s.shutdown(1) # By convention, but not actually necessary
        s.close()     # Remember to close sockets after use!
    except socket.error as socketerror:
        print("Error: ", socketerror)
```

Comment: I can't test it as it seems the IP is on your local network. The problem might be the s.recv part. If you're just looking to test wether the service is accepting connections, just add "return True" after s.close() and print the result of socket_to_me()

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Python 2 Socket HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html) to better understand the principles.

Answer (score 0):

Change 192.168.95.148 to 127.0.0.1 (localhost - connecting to yourself) and run [this program](https://archive.org/details/tucows_367516_Freefloat_FTP_Server) on the same machine. That way you'll have something to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

its a fake address, i think you are reading violent python if you want to make that work,
type **socket.gethostname()** instead of  **fake ip** address it will get connected to your machine.This is my code:

```
    def Socket_to_me(ip,port,time):
        try:
            s = socket.socket()
            s.settimeout(time)
            s.connect((ip,port))
            ans = s.recv(1024)
            print(ans)
            s.shutdown(1) # By convention, but not actually necessary
            s.close()     # Remember to close sockets after use!
        except socket.error as socketerror:
            print("Error: ", socketerror) 

call the method by:
Socket_to_me(socket.gethostname(),1234,10)
```